# EDI, 852 Product Transfer: N1 loop out of order?

Tags: format, report, edi

I have to build some EDI for a report I'm working on. I'm using [EDI Notepad](http://liaison.com/products/integrate/edi-notepad) to validate my output. While this EDI is perfectly readable by EDI Notepad, I keep getting errors that I have a few `N1` loops that are out of order. What gives?

I've been reading through the spec all afternoon trying to figure it out, and I see no mention of `N1` order anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the EDI in question:

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *12*ABCCOM         *01*999999999      *110127*1719*U*00400*000005438*0*P*>~
GS*PD*4405197800*999999999*20110127*1719*1421*X*004010VICS~
ST*852*000008315~
XQ*G*20130807*20130807~
N1*ST**11*AD6448446~
LIN**UA*53233*PI*76189053560~
ZA*QA*0*EA~
ZA*QS*0*EA~
LIN**UA*53234*PI*76189053430~
ZA*QA*0*EA~
ZA*QS*0*EA~
N1*ST**11*BD9628542~
LIN**UA*53234*PI*76189053430~
ZA*QA*30*EA~
ZA*QS*0*EA~
LIN**UA*53233*PI*76189053560~
ZA*QA*0*EA~
ZA*QS*60*EA~
N1*ST**11*FD0286244~
LIN**UA*53233*PI*76189053560~
ZA*QA*180*EA~
ZA*QS*930*EA~
LIN**UA*53234*PI*76189053430~
ZA*QA*390*EA~
ZA*QS*585*EA~
N1*ST**11*BD9076008~
LIN**UA*53234*PI*76189053430~
ZA*QA*0*EA~
ZA*QS*0*EA~
LIN**UA*53233*PI*76189053560~
ZA*QA*0*EA~
ZA*QS*0*EA~
N1*ST**11*FD0417825~
LIN**UA*53234*PI*76189053430~
ZA*QA*30*EA~
ZA*QS*30*EA~
LIN**UA*53233*PI*76189053560~
ZA*QA*0*EA~
ZA*QS*0*EA~
N1*ST**11*BW0222264~
LIN**UA*53234*PI*76189053430~
ZA*QA*90*EA~
ZA*QS*90*EA~
LIN**UA*53233*PI*76189053560~
ZA*QA*240*EA~
ZA*QS*60*EA~
CTT*12~
SE*46*000008315~
GE*1*1421~
IEA*1*000005438~
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the ANSI standard, you have an N1 as a child of the LIN, which is not part of the standard.  The SDQ segment was implemented for address / quantity in the detail loop.

If you remove the N1 segments (all but the one from the XQ), you'll notice EDI Notepad won't display an error.  If your spec has a detail N1, then they are using their own "version" of the standard.  Not uncommon, by any means.

Comment: Can you link me to some standards documents? I didn't have much luck yesterday... all I could find were vendor-specific EDI specs for various retailers.

Comment: Sadly, the standards are not published for free (unlike EDIFACT).  You can certainly go to DISA's website and browse their offerings (http://store.x12.org/store/asc-x12-guidelines)  Liaison, who makes the EDI Notepad utility, also sells a Dictionary Viewer.  Outside of that, what you found is what you are going to get (vendor specific implementation guides)